# How to access a population element?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following element in python:
p = [{('BOD', 'TLS'), ('TLS', 'CFE'), ('CFE', 'ORY'), ('TLS', 'BOD'), ('SXB', 'BOD')}]

How can I access the elements of p e.g ('BOD', 'TLS'), 'BOD', ('CFE', 'ORY'), 'ORY', etc.  ?

BR

p[0][0]
0
p[0][0][0]
*** TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p[0] = {('BOD', 'TLS'), ('TLS', 'CFE'), ('CFE', 'ORY'), ('TLS', 'BOD'), ('SXB', 'BOD')}` is a set.
You can convert the set to list, then slice the list and tuple.

```
a = list(p[0])
print(a[0])    # ('BOD', 'TLS')
print(a[0][0]) # 'BOD'
```